# Was Columbia’s CVR ever found?

Tags: space-shuttle, failure, shuttle-columbia

Each of the space shuttles carried a [cockpit voice recorder (CVR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_recorder#Cockpit_voice_recorder), similar to those required on commercial airliners, which recorded the crew’s conversations to aid in accident reconstruction should a shuttle orbiter be lost.

Of the two destroyed orbiters, *Challenger*’s CVR was definitely recovered (that’s how we know about the famous “uh-oh” at T+00:00:01:13, for instance), but I haven’t been able to find anything one way or the other about whether the same was true for *Columbia*’s CVR.

Was it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Orbiters did not have a Cockpit Voice Recorder.

They originally had a pair of Ops Recorders as part of the telemetry system, that could record downlinked telemetry, including voice.  This is what the post-failure voice was pulled off of in the Challenger accident.

The [official NASA voice transcript](https://history.nasa.gov/transcript.html) of the Challenger accident states that it comes from

> the Challenger operational recorder...

You can see the Ops Recorders in this diagram from the [1982 Press Manual](https://ia802904.us.archive.org/24/items/PressInformationSpaceShuttleTransportationSystemMarch1982/Press_Information_Space_Shuttle_Transportation_System_March_1982.pdf) and read an extensive description of them starting on page 389 of the manual.

[image]

In the case of the 2003 accident,

> **Neither of the ops recorders were recovered from the Columbia.** Only
>   one of the two would have contained the telemetry data that was being
>   transmitted back from the orbiter during the re-entry flight. Because
>   the telemetry data was fairly complete up until the loss of signal, in
>   spite of the various anomalous, but brief, communications drop outs,
>   the retrieval of the missing ops recorder would not have added that
>   much new data. A payload data recorder also exists, but it does not
>   contain much in the way of re-entry flight information. It was not
>   recovered from the wreckage debris, either.

(emphasis mine)

From [Volume 2](https://www.nasa.gov/columbia/caib/html/VOL2.html), Appendix D19 of the CAIB report, page 536.

Yet another recorder, the OEX recorder was found in East Texas. See [Do rockets, launch vehicles or spacecraft contain a black-box?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/30677/do-rockets-launch-vehicles-or-spacecraft-contain-a-black-box) This recorder contained vital data used in the accident investigation.

Eventually the Ops Recorders were replaced by Solid State Recorders (SSR) that served the same purpose. See page 2.4-10 in the [Space Shuttle Crew Operations Manual](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/pdf/390651main_shuttle_crew_operations_manual.pdf).